# How to Run Google Spreadsheet script from specific user?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Is it possible to run a script in google sheets from a specific user, regardless of the user that opens the sheet?

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: From a comment by the OP

> So basically id want to the script to run as/from User A at all times. For example. User B, C, or D can all open the sheet and run the script, however i'd want it to run as User A all the time.

Only Google Apps Script Web Apps and installable triggers could be ran as the owner/creator, other scripts doesn't require permissions or if the require them run as the user that executed the script.

---

## Short answer

Yes, it's possible.

## Explanation

Bounded to spreadsheet scripts could be ran by any user that has edit access to the spreadsheet. If there aren't custom menus, to run a script, the user should

1. Open the script editor, Tools > Script editor,
2. If the script is not in the default file, open the corresponding file that holds the script,
3. Select the script the the drop-down menu,
4. Click the Run button

## References

[Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question, which is about running a script _as a specific user_ (that is, with the rights that that user has).

Comment: The question says "from a..." not "as a..."

Comment: I don't see how you reconcile that position with "regardless of the user that opens the sheet"

Comment: So basically id want to the script to run as/from User A at all times. For example. User B, C, or D can all open the sheet and run the script, however i'd want it to run as User A all the time.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Triggers will do what I am I'm trying to accomplish, but I don't see how the rest of your answer works. If I(User A) write a script in a spreadsheet to download my Google Contacts into a sheet. Script works great for me. But if User B opens the sheet and runs the script its going to Download User B Contacts....not User A. And that's what I mean by making the script user specific. So that if User B opens the script and runs it, it would run as User A and download User A's contacts